# How to add arrow as accent with keyboard in Word 2007 Equation Editor

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, equations, equation-editor

I'm entering equations with vectors in, and getting a bit tired of having to use the Accents menu to add the arrow across the top of the vector symbols. So I'm looking for a way to do it using the keyboard.

I got this far `V\above(\rightarrow)`, but it doesn't give the same result:

[image]

(On the left is the result of the key sequence above, on the right is the result when using the menu)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`V\vec` and pressing space **twice** does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Putting Various accents in Equation Editor really easy with Math Auto Correct. In equation editor,

a\ddot two space after it (giving space is very important)  gives ä and so on. Please see this link for complete list of accent shortcut[Shortcut for typing accent in Equation Editor of MS Word](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_h7ukThU_4&t=5s) .

This works well in all the version of MS Word 2007 and higher.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer.  Just FYI, videos tend not to be real useful except  as supplemental clarifying information when everything is already in the answer.  Some users aren't able to play videos, the information can't be indexed, amateur videos can be hard to understand, and they are inefficient to view or to randomly access the content.  If you happen to come across text information you can link to instead, that would be great.